# Unbiased estimator.

Tags: calculus, statistics, functions

With sample variance defined as $S^2 =  (\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline{X})^2 )/(n-1)$

A. Show that $E(X_i^2) = \sigma^2 + \mu^2$ using the fact that $\sigma^2 = E((X_i - \mu)^2)$

Comment: Although we can guess that $X_i$ should be independent, identically distributed normal random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, you should make this explicit.

Comment: Updated, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

a.)  For any random variable $X$ with $|\mu| < \infty$,

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(X) &= \text{E}[(X - \mu)^2] \\
&= \text{E}[X^2 + \mu^2 - 2 \text{E}(X) \mu] \\
&= \text{E}(X^2) - \mu^2 .
\end{align}
$$

b.)

$$
\begin{align}
\text{E}(S^2) &= \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \text{E}[(X_i - \bar{X})^2] \\
&= \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left [ \text{E}(X_i^2) + \text{E}(\bar{X}^2) - 2 \text{E}(X_i \bar{X}) \right ] \\
&= \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left [ \sigma^2 + \mu^2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2 - 2 (\mu^2 + \text{Cov}(X_i, \bar{X})) \right ] \\
&= \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left [ \sigma^2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{n} - 2 \text{Cov}(X_i, \bar{X}) \right ] .
\end{align}
$$

Now since $\text{Cov}(X_i, X_j) = 0$ when $i \neq j$ and $\text{Cov}(X_i, X_i) = \text{Var}(X_i) = \sigma^2$,

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(X_i, \bar{X}) &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \text{Cov}(X_i, X_j) \\
&= \frac{\sigma^2}{n} ,
\end{align}
$$

which means,

$$
\begin{align}
\text{E}(S^2) &= \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left [ \sigma^2 + \frac{\sigma^2}{n} - \frac{2 \sigma^2}{n} \right ] \\
&= \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(n - 1) \sigma^2}{n} \\
&= \sigma^2.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The one step in your proof which is not basically just algebra is where you say that $\text{Cov}(X_i,\overline{X})=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. I think that warrants a short comment explaining where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

If the $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then here is where you start. First, the mean and variance are related to the expectations through:
$$
E(X_i) = \mu\\
E((X_i-\mu)^2) = \sigma^2
$$

**Extended Hint: Part A**

Expand the square in that second relationship:
$$
\sigma^2 = E((X_i-\mu)^2) = E(X_i^2-2X_i\mu+\mu^2)
$$
Then you'll apply the rules you know about expectation:

1. The expectation of a sum of terms is the sum of the expectation of those terms.
2. All terms that are not functions of $X_i$ are not random variables
   and so they can be pulled out of the expectation operators.
3. Substitute the relationships you know to put some expectations in
   terms of the known $\mu$.
4. Simplify and rearrange and you should have derived the result.

**Extended Hint: Part B**
Begin calculating the requested quantity:
$$
E(S^2) = E\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2\right)
$$
Again, start expanding and apply the above rules. You'll need an extra one this time, which is that the expectation of the sample mean is the true mean, $E(\bar{X})=\mu$. Also, you might have to apply the result you got previously, and know that the sum over $n$ terms of a constant is just $n$ times that constant. Good luck.

The basic idea idea worked out here, but you'll have to switch an $n$ for an $n-1$ to directly get the result:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance

Comment: Normality has nothing to do with anything here.

Comment: Am I missing something? That formula is not the unbiased estimator of the variance for an arbitrary distribution....or so I believed. I could be wrong...

Comment: Okay yeah, I was wrong. Thanks